# What are UK immigration officers looking for when confirming Registered Traveller status?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration

I recently applied for, and received provisional acceptance for, the Registered Traveller service.  I am a US citizen and frequent traveller to the UK (2-3 times a year), with absolutely no record of issues whatsoever.

I will be in the next couple of days going to the UK.  The [UK government website](https://www.gov.uk/registered-traveller) says that, when I arrive in the UK:

> The immigration officer will check that you meet the criteria and tell you that you can become a member if you do.

I am a little confused by this, as I already provided all of my details to demonstrate that I met the criteria for this service.  What exactly will the immigration officer be looking for? Simply that I exist? Do I need to bring any paperwork, or expect any additional questions (i.e. additional to the "standard" questions asked of all visitors)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s an online application and the first time you appear, in person, the immigration officer confirms that [you meet the criteria](https://www.faster-uk-entry.service.gov.uk/about#eligibility):

- that you are who you said you are when you remotely connected to the Internet and filled out the form;
- that your passport is from one of the eligible countries;
- that you visited four times in the previous 24 months (and in the specified categories), verified by the UK entry and exit records;
- that your travel purpose, immigration status and visa (as applicable) is what you indicated online.

As it applies to you, you would want to bring the relevant visa (exclusions are Tier 5 Sporting & Creative Concessions, EEA family permits, discretionary leave and leave outside the rules).